# Instagram API with prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, instagram

I am trying to add prettyPhoto to my pictures from my instagram feed on my website which can be seen at [www.dirtycookie.co](http://www.dirtycookie.co)

I can successfully pull the pictures from the instagram API however, I cannot add the prettyPhoto functionality to the pictures in the feed. Here is my ajax call with the prettyPhoto hook:

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<?=$user_id?>/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < <?=$num_to_display?>; i++) {
           jQuery('.instagram').append('<div class="instagram-placeholder"><a href="' + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url + '"  rel="prettyPhoto"><img alt="'+ data.data[i].caption.text +'" class="instagram-image" src="' + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +'"/></a></div>');  
            }     

        }
    });
});

</script>
```

It almost behaves as if the jquery.prettyPhoto.js is not being called, I have confirmed it is in the /js/ folder.

Here is my init script and the bottom of the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
```

Using Firebug I can see the Ajax is putting in the rel="prettyPhoto" properly.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching the prettyPhoto() function on the anchors at 'domready', even before the content is pulled in from the AJAX call. Hence its not working.
Try this.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<?=$user_id?>/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < <?=$num_to_display?>; i++) {
           jQuery('.instagram').append('<div class="instagram-placeholder"><a href="' + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url + '"  rel="prettyPhoto"><img alt="'+ data.data[i].caption.text +'" class="instagram-image" src="' + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +'"/></a></div>');  
            }     
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

        }
    });
});
```